# How to create a overlaying bottom content panel?

Tags: html, css

I have a `div` that needs to just create a bottom content panel, sort of like the Devtools, that appears at the bottom of the page, takes up the entire width of the screen, but on top of whatever is on the current page.

```
#panel {
position:absolute;
bottom:0%;
width: 100%;
height: 25%;
z-index:500;
}
```

However, the panel seems squished and the content inside the `#panel` `div` is not showing up.

Comment: Can you include the HTML so we can see what's happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are actually really close to making that happen, all you need is two adjustments.

Change `position: absolute;` to `position: fixed;` so that your panel will stay at the same place throughout the entire page.

I also recommend using `bottom: 0px;` instead of `bottom: 0%;` because  it will give you more control should you need to change something.

And last but not least you need to add `left: 0px;` to set its position.

So your final CSS should look like this:

```
#panel {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0px;
    Left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 25%;
    z-index:500;
}
```

Comment: how do I make this not overlap but push up the contents on the page instead?

Comment: @user299709 I'm not so sure what you are trying to say but maybe you should ask this in a different question.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/vwam5hvm/1/) is the basic version of what you asked.

Use the below css

```
position: fixed;
background-color: white;
border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
```

Position absolute, will not make your div fixed, when you scroll, it moves accordingly. So use fixed position, which will not scroll and also set the background-color else the content behind will overlaps, and it looks like transparent. To avoid it, use the background-color css property.

Comment: this is a great answer don't get me wrong but I think the other guy topped it!

Comment: Hmm, that's alright. Just to point out, there is a 12 minutes gap between the answer you chose and mine, which already had fiddle demo.

Comment: how do I make it so that it pushes up the existing content on the page up instead of overlaying?

Answer (score 0):

Changing `absolute` to `fixed` should do the trick.